# react app not deployed correctly with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

This my first time deploying a react app with firebase and after seeing a few tutorials I still get the same result . When I click on my firebase url to my website I get this pic instead of my website :
[image]

I followed the steps below :

```
1)cd to my react app 
2) npm install firebase-tools -g 
3)firebase login 
4) firebase init 
   -hosting setup 
What do you want to use as your public directory? build 
 Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
 Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
 File build /index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
  Skipping write of build /index.html
5) npm run build 
6) firebase deploy
```

So the deployment is succesfull but I do not get my app but this screen instead .

Comment: I don't see how your react app is involved at all in those instructions.  If you want to deploy something, you'll have to place some content in the public folder.  By default, you get what you see in your screenshot.

Comment: @DougStevenson what do you mean by placing something in the folder could you provide an example ? When you say public I think of the public folder build with create react app

Comment: I think you might want to review the documentation for Firebase Hosting very carefully, as you have missed some details about the public folder.  It needs to contains the content you want to deploy.  Hosting doesn't know what you want to do by default - you have to be clear.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: @DougStevenson In my .firebasesrc I have my project as default in the "projects" object I chose my project in the beggining

Comment: Those things have nothing to do with placing content in the folder user for deployment.  You chose "build". Now, you will have to remove what was put there by default, and put content in there to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart):

> **Specify a directory to use as your public root directory.**
>
> This directory contains all your publicly served static files,
> including your index.html file and any other assets that you want to
> deploy to Firebase Hosting.
>
> The default for the public root directory is called public.
>
> You can specify your public root directory now or you can specify it later in your firebase.json configuration file.
>
> If you select the default and don't already have a directory called public, Firebase creates it for you.
>
> If you don't already have a valid index.html file or 404.html file in your public root directory, Firebase creates them for you.

You created a public folder called "build", but you didn't put your app code in it.  It contains default content, as described by the documentation.  You will have to remove that default content and add your own.  Then, deploy again.

Comment: I will try it  . It just seemed weird to me to drag and drop all my files to that build file

Comment: Consider telling your react build to place the files in there instead.  Or figure out a command line to copy everything from one place to another.